# Should 'known as' be followed by quotation marks?

Tags: punctuation, british-english

e..g
This is how he became known as 'the ape king'.
or
'from then on, he became known as 'the smartest man in Britain'.

Or should this be without quotation marks?

Answer (score -1):

Generally the quotations marks would only apply if you're actually quoting somebody. So, using your example, if somebody had actually described him as "the smartest man in Britain", then you'd use quotation marks. If you're paraphrasing, then don't use them. So, if a person was generally known as the ape king, but you aren't specifically quoting somebody who has said that, you'd leave out the quotes.

Comment: Also, there are ["scare quotes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes)